# Swift problem with sending data to another ViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

Variable `cards` in second ViewController should be updated in first VC on buttonClick. 
I tested the sending data from the first VC with printing data and it works good. 
Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let secondVC = (mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController)
    for card in setsOfCardsByLevel {
        cardVC.cards.append(card)
    }
    print("Number of cards to send - \(cardVC.secondVC.count)") //PRINTS RIGHT NUMBER
    presentVC("SecondViewController") //WORKS FINE
}
```

Maybe you dont need this method below but I will put it just in case:

```
func presentVC(_ VC_Name: String) {
    guard let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: VC_Name) else { return }
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myVC)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.navigationController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**PROBLEM:** When I print `cards` in the secondViewController, they are empty(count = 0). How? 
**EDIT:** While waiting for answer on StackOverflow I changed presentViewController to pushViewController and print in `secondVC` shows right number. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your presentVC method. First in your `btnTapped` method you instantiate your second viewController and assing your cards, again in your `presentVC` method instantiate another controller and it's not relevant to the first you define in your btnTapped and cards variable not assigned. For solution you can pass your secondVC as a parameter to your presentVC, not the name of storyboard